# How can i send the outputStream from different method with connect?

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth

I want to connect to device by choosing from the list of device and send the message by using a button, but i try to separate the method and get error of `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.OutputStream.write(byte[])' on a null object reference`.

This is my current code:

```
@ReactMethod
public void sendMessage2(String message, String deviceAddress, Promise promise) {
    BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);
    try {
        BluetoothSocket socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
        socket.connect();
        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(message.getBytes());
        outputStream.flush();

        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;
        bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);
        String response = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);

        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
        socket.close();

        promise.resolve(response);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        promise.reject(new Throwable(e.getMessage()));
    }
}
```

is it possible to separate into two method, connect and send message?